# How to inject external script with chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It's my first time I'm programming chrome extension.

I need to load an external script by using chrome extension to the current page.
Right now I'm loading the script by using debugger mode (f12), and inside the console tab I'm running getScript("http://www.mypath.com/....") and I want to pass all that by making single click chrome extension.

what I did so far (by reading some tutrials) is that

manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "first extention",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.12.4.min.js", "test.js"]
    }
  ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>", "http://www.mypath.com*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "http://*.google.com/" ],
    "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
     "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://www.mypath.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

popup.html file

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" name="btn">click here</button>

    <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js file

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", getUrl);
function getUrl() {  
jQuery.getScript("http://www.mypath.com/.....");
}
```

appear that it's not working,
can someone put some light on it?

thanks

Comment: You'll run into all sorts of problems with that approach because of chrome's security concerns.  It can be made to work with the right permissions, but the far better approach is to save the script locally in your extension's directory and load it from there.  Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

test.js

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {file:"http://www.mypath.com/....."});
    });
```

or

```
function getUrl() {  
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {file:"http://www.mypath.com/....."});
}
```

manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://www.mypath.com"
 ],
```

ref : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript